# nearest building with open street map

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I have a csv of relevant points with latitude and longitude and trying to get the nearest
building data to each point and add a column to the csv (or panda) in python. Tried using Pyrosm and various libraries but can't seem to prune the data to get the nearest building and then add the data. Thanks
This is what I have

```
from pyrosm import OSM
from pyrosm import get_data
import geopandas as gpd
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np
import osmnx as ox

# get rid of weird error
import shapely
import warnings
from shapely.errors import ShapelyDeprecationWarning
import csv

def get_gig_data(csv_fname):
  with open(csv_fname, "r", encoding="latin-1") as gig_records:
    for gig_record in csv.reader(gig_records):
      yield gig_record

def main():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=ShapelyDeprecationWarning) 


    chicago_osm = OSM(get_data("chicago"))


    #get a Point of Interest GeoDataFrame 

    points_of_interest = chicago_osm.get_pois() #can use a custom filter if we want to filter the types, but I think no filter might be the best

    # get buildings nodes and edges
    nodes, edges = chicago_osm.get_network(nodes=True, network_type="walking")
    buildings = chicago_osm.get_buildings()
    b_cnt = len(buildings)
    G = chicago_osm.to_graph(nodes, edges)
    #nodes = get_igraph_nodes(G)

    buildings['geometry'] = buildings.centroid




    # poi_list = np.asarray([ point.coords for point in points_of_interest['geometry'] ]) #if point.geom_type == point])

    #print(poi_list.shape)

    #tree = BallTree( np.asarray([ point.coords for point in points_of_interest['geometry'] if point.geom_type == point]), metric="manhattan") #Note: the scipy implementation of manhattan/cityblock distance might be faster according to the internet bc it uses a C function
    #Read in the gig work data - I think the best way to do this will probably be with the CSV.reader with open thing because it will go line by line and save a ton of memory

    '''for i in points_of_interest:
    print('Type: ', type(i) , '  ',i)'''

    gig_fp = "data_sample.csv"
    #gig_data = gpd.read_file(gig_fp) 

    iter_gig = iter(get_gig_data(gig_fp))
    next(iter_gig)

    ids=dict()
    for building in buildings.iterrows():
        #print(type(building[1][32]) , '  ', building[1][32])
        #tup = tuple(float(x) for x in [trip[17][8:-1].split()])
        ids[building[1][32]] = building



    #make the tree that determines closest POI


    #if we use the CSV reader this for loop will be done already


    for trip in iter_gig:
        # Using generator so this should be efficient memory wise.
        tup = tuple([float(x) for x in trip[17][8:-1].split() ])
        print(type(tup), '  ', tup)
        src_ids,euclidean_distance=ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G,tup)
        src_ids, euclidean_distance= ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G,tup)
        # find nearest node


    #THEN ADD THE PICKUP AND DROPOFF IDS TO THIS TUPLE AND ADD TO A NEW NP ARRAY


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```